# how to visualize a lot of entities in diagram?

Tags: java, uml, diagram, visualize

I am using ObjectAid UML as eclipse plugin, then I generate entities diagram from my project, there are a lot of relationships which is nested between each other and it looks like a mess. I need a good solution to visualize about 60~ entities in my project via diagram. Any suggestions? Also I found JPA Entities Editor, but it works only with specific project's type - JPA project. So it doesnt fit. Thanks, in advance (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You could shorten the class blocks by showing only connections and any without attributes in blocks.
- You could lower the number of connections by showing the generalization by ":" notation only, without arrows. (`child:parent` in the name of block)
- You could hide dependencies
- you can lower the number of connections by moving the named ends inside the class-owners (attributes in block instead of association)
- But the only serious way is to make a `component diagram`, where components are the groups of close classes and later make `class diagram`s for each component separately.

Comment: Thanks, I split into components